TypeError: 'async for' requires an object with __aiter__ method, got coroutine
Has anyone encountered the same error? Is there any solution?
error log

TypeError: 'async for' requires an object with __aiter__ method, got coroutine

the detial log


TypeError: 'async for' requires an object with __aiter__ method, got coroutine
2024-09-07 01:45:17.358 | DEBUG    | meilisync.main:_:36 
- plugins=['meilisync.plugin.Plugin'] progress=Progress(type=<ProgressType.file: 'file'>) 
debug=True source=Source(type=<SourceType.postgres: 'postgres'>, 
database='postgres', host='192.168.101.194', port=5432, user='postgres', 
password='postgres') meilisearch=MeiliSearch(api_url='http://192.168.101.194:7700/',
api_key='api_key', insert_size=1000, 
insert_interval=10) sync=[Sync(plugins=[], table='document_info', pk='id', 
full=True, index='document_info', fields=None), Sync(plugins=[], 
table='document_content', pk='doc_id', full=True, index='document_content', fields=None)] sentry=None
/meilisync/meilisync/main.py:89: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Postgres.get_full_data' was never awaited
  async for items in source.get_full_data(sync, meili_settings.insert_size or 10000):
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
╭───────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ──────────────────────╮
│ /meilisync/meilisync/main.py:140 in start                                    │
│                                                                              │
│   137 │   │   lock = asyncio.Lock()                                          │
│   138 │   │   await asyncio.gather(_(), interval())                          │
│   139 │                                                                      │
│ ❱ 140 │   asyncio.run(run())                                                 │
│   141                                                                        │
│   142                                                                        │
│   143 @app.command(help="Refresh all data by swap index")                    │
│                                                                              │
│ ╭───────────────────────────────── locals ─────────────────────────────────╮ │
│ │                _ = <function start.<locals>._ at 0x7f13141423e0>         │ │
│ │       collection = <meilisync.event.EventCollection object at            │ │
│ │                    0x7f13140eb3b0>                                       │ │
│ │          context = <click.core.Context object at 0x7f1314257440>         │ │
│ │ current_progress = None                                                  │ │
│ │         interval = <function start.<locals>.interval at 0x7f1314142340>  │ │
│ │             lock = <asyncio.locks.Lock object at 0x7f1314122870          │ │
│ │                    [unlocked]>                                           │ │
│ │            meili = <meilisync.meili.Meili object at 0x7f1314becaa0>      │ │
│ │   meili_settings = MeiliSearch(                                          │ │
│ │                    │   api_url='http://192.168.101.194:7700/',           │ │
│ │                    │                                                     │ │
│ │                    api_key='api_key'                                     │ │
│ │                    │   insert_size=1000,                                 │ │
│ │                    │   insert_interval=10                                │ │
│ │                    )                                                     │ │
│ │         progress = <meilisync.progress.file.File object at                │ │
│ │                    0x7f1314d021e0>                                       │ │
│ │              run = <function start.<locals>.run at 0x7f1314142a20>       │ │
│ │         settings = Settings(                                             │ │
│ │                    │   plugins=['meilisync.plugin.Plugin'],              │ │
│ │                    │   progress=Progress(                                │ │
│ │                    │   │   type=<ProgressType.file: 'file'>                │ │
│ │                    │   ),                                                │ │
│ │                    │   debug=True,                                       │ │
│ │                    │   source=Source(                                    │ │
│ │                    │   │   type=<SourceType.postgres: 'postgres'>,       │ │
│ │                    │   │   database='postgres',                          │ │
│ │                    │   │   host='192.168.101.194',                       │ │
│ │                    │   │   port=5432,                                    │ │
│ │                    │   │   user='postgres',                              │ │
│ │                    │   │   password='postgres'                           │ │
│ │                    │   ),                                                │ │
│ │                    │   meilisearch=MeiliSearch(                          │ │
│ │                    │   │   api_url='http://192.168.101.194:7700/',       │ │
│ │                    │   │                                                 │ │
│ │                    api_key='  api_key   '                                │ │
│ │                    │   │   insert_size=1000,                             │ │
│ │                    │   │   insert_interval=10                            │ │
│ │                    │   ),                                                │ │
│ │                    │   sync=[                                            │ │
│ │                    │   │   Sync(                                         │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   plugins=[],                               │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   table='document_info',                    │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   pk='id',                                  │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   full=True,                                │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   index='document_info',                    │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   fields=None                               │ │
│ │                    │   │   ),                                            │ │
│ │                    │   │   Sync(                                         │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   plugins=[],                               │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   table='document_content',                 │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   pk='doc_id',                              │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   full=True,                                │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   index='document_content',                 │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   fields=None                               │ │
│ │                    │   │   )                                             │ │
│ │                    │   ],                                                │ │
│ │                    │   sentry=None                                       │ │
│ │                    )                                                     │ │
│ │           source = <meilisync.source.postgres.Postgres object at         │ │
│ │                    0x7f1315be33b0>                                       │ │
│ ╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯ │
│                                                                              │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py:194 in run                      │
│                                                                              │
│   191 │   │   │   "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop" │
│   192 │                                                                      │
│   193 │   with Runner(debug=debug, loop_factory=loop_factory) as runner:     │
│ ❱ 194 │   │   return runner.run(main)                                        │
│   195                                                                        │
│   196                                                                        │
│   197 def _cancel_all_tasks(loop):                                           │
│                                                                              │
│ ╭──────────────────────────────── locals ────────────────────────────────╮   │
│ │        debug = None                                                    │   │
│ │ loop_factory = None                                                    │   │
│ │         main = <coroutine object start.<locals>.run at 0x7f13140d7140> │   │
│ │       runner = <asyncio.runners.Runner object at 0x7f13140ea2a0>       │   │
│ ╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯   │
│                                                                              │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py:118 in run                      │
│                                                                              │
│   115 │   │                                                                  │
│   116 │   │   self._interrupt_count = 0                                      │
│   117 │   │   try:                                                           │
│ ❱ 118 │   │   │   return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)                 │
│   119 │   │   except exceptions.CancelledError:                              │
│   120 │   │   │   if self._interrupt_count > 0:                              │
│   121 │   │   │   │   uncancel = getattr(task, "uncancel", None)             │
│                                                                              │
│ ╭───────────────────────────────── locals ─────────────────────────────────╮ │
│ │        context = <_contextvars.Context object at 0x7f1314086ec0>         │ │
│ │           coro = <coroutine object start.<locals>.run at 0x7f13140d7140> │ │
│ │           self = <asyncio.runners.Runner object at 0x7f13140ea2a0>       │ │
│ │ sigint_handler = functools.partial(<bound method Runner._on_sigint of    │ │
│ │                  <asyncio.runners.Runner object at 0x7f13140ea2a0>>,     │ │
│ │                  main_task=<Task finished name='Task-4'                  │ │
│ │                  coro=<start.<locals>.run() done, defined at             │ │
│ │                  /meilisync/meilisync/main.py:135>                       │ │
│ │                  exception=TypeError("'async for' requires an object     │ │
│ │                  with __aiter__ method, got coroutine")>)                │ │
│ │           task = <Task finished name='Task-4' coro=<start.<locals>.run() │ │
│ │                  done, defined at /meilisync/meilisync/main.py:135>      │ │
│ │                  exception=TypeError("'async for' requires an object     │ │
│ │                  with __aiter__ method, got coroutine")>                 │ │
│ ╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯ │
│                                                                              │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py:664 in run_until_complete   │
│                                                                              │
│    661 │   │   if not future.done():                                         │
│    662 │   │   │   raise RuntimeError('Event loop stopped before Future comp'│
│    663 │   │                                                                 │
│ ❱  664 │   │   return future.result()                                        │
│    665 │                                                                     │
│    666 │   def stop(self):                                                   │
│    667 │   │   """Stop running the event loop. """                           │
│                                                                              │
│ ╭───────────────────────────────── locals ─────────────────────────────────╮ │
│ │   future = <Task finished name='Task-4' coro=<start.<locals>.run() done,  │ │
│ │            defined at /meilisync/meilisync/main.py:135>                   │ │
│ │            exception=TypeError("'async for' requires an object with      │ │
│ │            __aiter__ method, got coroutine")>                            │ │
│ │ new_task = False                                                         │ │
│ │     self = <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=True             │ │
│ │            debug=False>                                                  │ │
│ ╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯ │
│                                                                              │
│ /meilisync/meilisync/main.py:138 in run                                      │
│                                                                              │
│   135 │   async def run():                                                   │
│   136 │   │   nonlocal lock                                                  │
│   137 │   │   lock = asyncio.Lock()                                          │
│ ❱ 138 │   │   await asyncio.gather(_(), interval())                          │
│   139 │                                                                      │
│   140 │   asyncio.run(run())                                                 │
│   141                                                                        │
│                                                                              │
│ ╭────────────────────────────── locals ───────────────────────────────╮      │
│ │        _ = <function start.<locals>._ at 0x7f13141423e0>            │      │
│ │ interval = <function start.<locals>.interval at 0x7f1314142340>     │      │
│ │     lock = <asyncio.locks.Lock object at 0x7f1314122870 [unlocked]> │      │
│ ╰─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯      │
│                                                                              │
│ /meilisync/meilisync/main.py:89 in _                                         │
│                                                                              │
│    86 │   │   for sync in settings.sync:                                     │
│    87 │   │   │   if sync.full and not await meili.index_exists(sync.index_n │
│    88 │   │   │   │   count = 0                                              │
│ ❱  89 │   │   │   │   async for items in source.get_full_data(sync, meili_se │
│    90 │   │   │   │   │   count += len(items)                                │
│    91 │   │   │   │   │   await meili.add_full_data(sync, items)             │
│    92 │   │   │   │   if count:                                              │
│                                                                              │
│ ╭───────────────────────────────── locals ─────────────────────────────────╮ │
│ │       collection = <meilisync.event.EventCollection object at            │ │
│ │                    0x7f13140eb3b0>                                       │ │
│ │            count = 0                                                     │ │
│ │ current_progress = None                                                  │ │
│ │             lock = <asyncio.locks.Lock object at 0x7f1314122870          │ │
│ │                    [unlocked]>                                           │ │
│ │            meili = <meilisync.meili.Meili object at 0x7f1314becaa0>      │ │
│ │   meili_settings = MeiliSearch(                                          │ │
│ │                    │   api_url='http://192.168.101.194:7700/',           │ │
│ │                    │                                                     │ │
│ │                    api_key=''                                            │ │
│ │                    │   insert_size=1000,                                 │ │
│ │                    │   insert_interval=10                                │ │
│ │                    )                                                     │ │
│ │         progress = <meilisync.progress.file.File object at                │ │
│ │                    0x7f1314d021e0>                                       │ │
│ │         settings = Settings(                                             │ │
│ │                    │   plugins=['meilisync.plugin.Plugin'],              │ │
│ │                    │   progress=Progress(                                │ │
│ │                    │   │   type=<ProgressType.file: 'file'>                │ │
│ │                    │   ),                                                │ │
│ │                    │   debug=True,                                       │ │
│ │                    │   source=Source(                                    │ │
│ │                    │   │   type=<SourceType.postgres: 'postgres'>,       │ │
│ │                    │   │   database='postgres',                          │ │
│ │                    │   │   host='192.168.101.194',                       │ │
│ │                    │   │   port=5432,                                    │ │
│ │                    │   │   user='postgres',                              │ │
│ │                    │   │   password='postgres'                           │ │
│ │                    │   ),                                                │ │
│ │                    │   meilisearch=MeiliSearch(                          │ │
│ │                    │   │   api_url='http://192.168.101.194:7700/',       │ │
│ │                    │   │                                                 │ │
│ │                    api_key='api_key' │ │
│ │                    │   │   insert_size=1000,                             │ │
│ │                    │   │   insert_interval=10                            │ │
│ │                    │   ),                                                │ │
│ │                    │   sync=[                                            │ │
│ │                    │   │   Sync(                                         │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   plugins=[],                               │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   table='document_info',                    │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   pk='id',                                  │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   full=True,                                │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   index='document_info',                    │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   fields=None                               │ │
│ │                    │   │   ),                                            │ │
│ │                    │   │   Sync(                                         │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   plugins=[],                               │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   table='document_content',                 │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   pk='doc_id',                              │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   full=True,                                │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   index='document_content',                 │ │
│ │                    │   │   │   fields=None                               │ │
│ │                    │   │   )                                             │ │
│ │                    │   ],                                                │ │
│ │                    │   sentry=None                                       │ │
│ │                    )                                                     │ │
│ │           source = <meilisync.source.postgres.Postgres object at         │ │
│ │                    0x7f1315be33b0>                                       │ │
│ │             sync = Sync(                                                 │ │
│ │                    │   plugins=[],                                       │ │
│ │                    │   table='document_info',                            │ │
│ │                    │   pk='id',                                          │ │
│ │                    │   full=True,                                        │ │
│ │                    │   index='document_info',                            │ │
│ │                    │   fields=None                                       │ │
│ │                    )                                                     │ │
│ ╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯ │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
TypeError: 'async for' requires an object with __aiter__ method, got coroutine


meilisync_config.yml
debug: true
plugins:
  - meilisync.plugin.Plugin
progress:
  type: file
source:
  type: postgres
  host: 192.168.101.194
  port: 5432
  database: postgres
  user: postgres
  password: "postgres"
meilisearch:
  api_url: http://192.168.101.194:7700/
  api_key: 'api_key'
  insert_size: 1000
  insert_interval: 10
sync:
  - table: document_info
    index: document_info
    pk: id
    full: true
  - table: document_content
    index: document_content
    pk: doc_id
    full: true


docker-compose.yml
services:
  meilisync:
    image: long2ice/meilisync:latest
    # platform: linux/x86_64
    volumes:
      - ./meilisync/meilisync_config.yml:/meilisync/config.yml
    networks:
      - pub-network
    restart: always
  postgres_db:
    image: postgres:16.4
    container_name: docker_postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: anzw2000
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./postgres/log:/var/log/postgresql
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    networks:
      - pub-network
  meilisearch_server:
    image: getmeili/meilisearch:v1.10.0
    container_name: meilisearch_server
    ports:
      - "7700:7700"
    environment:
      MEILI_MASTER_KEY: 'api_key'
    volumes:
      - ./meili_data:/meili_data
    networks:
      - pub-network
networks:
  pub-network:
    driver: bridge


rebuilding the docker container.
try to remove the

progress:
  type: file
  path: myprogress.json

